# Flush data in php complex loop

Tags: php, ajax, flush

I am trying to update information on front end while processing is in progress at back end. For this purpose I am using php flush function.

My code is

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
    $varint=$varint+1;
    $curr_id = $row['Item'];
    $toret['row_num']=$varint;
    $toret['curr_url']=$curr_id;

    echo json_encode($toret);
    flush();

    $this->scrape_one_id($curr_id);
    $value['arrow_id']=$curr_id;
    $this->ahm->insert_new_id($curr_id);
    $this->ahm->insert_current($value);
}
```

I have tried it in many ways but it only sends back first echo only and sends rest after complete execution is finished. It works fine if **scrape_one_id** function is commented.

Some of the methods I have tried are:

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
    $varint=$varint+1;
    $curr_id = $row['Item'];
    $toret['row_num']=$varint;
    $toret['curr_url']=$curr_id;

    echo json_encode($toret);
    if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) ob_flush();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    flush();
    if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) ob_clean();

    $this->scrape_one_id($curr_id);
    $value['arrow_id']=$curr_id;
    $this->ahm->insert_new_id($curr_id);
    $this->ahm->insert_current($value);
}
```

It also worked fine without **scrape_one_id** function

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just read few caveats here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try adding ob_flush() in there.

Edit: in your first code , just put ob_flush() after your first flush()
and see how that works.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web
>   server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the
>   browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering
>   mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and
>   flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.

Comment: in the second code, with conditions ... i was talking about the first source code. updated my answer.

Comment: Then you might have to check further down the rabbit hole. check the infrastructure.
How is php running ? apache2mod ? cgi ? reverse proxy in there ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that there is a function to replace `ob_flush` and `flush`. If you set `ob_implicit_flush(true);` at the top of the page it will automatically flush any echo or print you do in the rest of the script.

Note that you still need a minimum amount of data to come through the browser filter. I would advice using `str_pad($text,4096);` since this automatically lenghtens the text with spaces to 4 KB which is the minimum limit when using FireFox and linux.

You should read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) (caveats) and also comments there.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried `ob_implicit_flush` as well. But it gives me the same result.
1st output is fine all the rest are at the completion of execution.

Comment: Did you also use `str_pad`?

Comment: yes, I tried that as well.
The first output is like 50 or 60 characters and it is printed immediately, but all the rest are printed only after the complete execution

Comment: What is in `scrape_one_id` function?

Comment: It has curl requests and HTML processing. It also calls another function which saves the data in MySQL Database through a call to CodeIgniter Model function